# Splitting xml file in command line based on an element properties

Tags: xml, command-line

I have huge xml file with different nodes and properties. I used `grep -c` to count the products with specific type. here is what I have done so far :

```
grep -c "</products>" products.xml // output : 200023

grep -c '<product type="cloths"' products.xml   // output :  8039
```

So I need to extract all products with type cloths as a tree in a new.xml file without all other properties so that I can import the new.xml file into a database :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
   <product type="cloths" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <price>39.95</price>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
      <catalog_item gender="Women's">
         <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
         <price>42.50</price>
         <size description="Small">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Extra Large">
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
</catalog>
```

Comment: XSLT is ideal for this.  Is that an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have XSLT for the huge file I have. Don't know if there is any method to generate such file! sorry new to xml world. Thanks

Comment: It would be simple to write XSLT for your task.  Are you able to run XSLT if you had XSLT code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sample showing `grep` and the command-line tag applied to the question, it looks like you want a pure command line solution.  One option would be to use [`xmllint`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint) to run an XPath query that selects only the products with type "cloths".

```
> xmllint --xpath /catalog/product[@type=\"cloths\"] products.xml
<product type="cloths" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
      <catalog_item gender="Men's">
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <price>39.95</price>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
      <catalog_item gender="Women's">
         <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
         <price>42.50</price>
         <size description="Small">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Extra Large">
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
         </size>
      </catalog_item>
   </product>
```

Note however that this doesn't produce a well-formed XML document.  It's only a node set containing what the XPath query selected.  However, you could then wrap it in some additional scripting to produce a full XML document.

```
printf '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n' > cloths.xml
printf '<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">\n' >> cloths.xml
printf '<catalog>\n' >> cloths.xml
xmllint --xpath /catalog/product[@type=\"cloths\"] products.xml >> cloths.xml
printf '\n</catalog>\n' >> cloths.xml
```

I have omitted error checking between these commands to simplify the code sample.

You also mentioned that the input XML file is huge.  Depending on how huge, this approach might not scale well in terms of memory consumption.  If that's a problem, then you might need to take more of a streaming approach to the problem, reading in small portions of the input document at a time and processing it incrementally.  This would likely go beyond the realm of the command line and into custom coding.  One example of a streaming XML API is StAX in Java.  Here is a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/).

Comment: Thanks. but the xmllint doesn't work it shows `XPath set is empty
` I have googled it to figure out what is the problem! no luck.

Comment: @Mtaly, `XPath set is empty` means that the XPath query executed but didn't match anything, so the result set is empty.  If your XML is truly like what you gave in the question, then this shouldn't happen.  See this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/cnauroth/ffc95773560612e5bcb1) for a successful demonstration of the command.  The script embeds the XML I was expecting as a heredoc, so you'll get predictable results.  If your XML is actually a bit different than what you described, then you might need to adjust the XPath query.